# How to scrape javascript hash links content?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Hi im a bit new in web scraping using Puppeter im currently im facing the next problem:

in the site where im trying to extract information i have a bootstrap table with a typical js pagination like the examples from:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/pagination/

when i check the page html with Chrome inspector all i can see is **2** and when i check link location i see

https://webpage.com/works#

how i can know how many pages are in total? and how i can click them? i don't understand how i can visit every page for this type of pagination.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try till now? Any code snippet?

Comment: This is pretty big code to write normally. If you manage to do more research, I will update my answer. I have some amount of code, but need to properly format and see what you got. :)

Comment: Can you mark the answer as accepted or comment out? I am seeing duplicate questions but cannot point to this one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no foolproof way, but I deal with pagination in this order,

- Wait for the target element to appear
- Collect the data from target
- Remove the target element
- Click next button
- ...loop thru until there are no next button or content doesn't load even after wait

## Proof of concept:

Target HTML Code:

```html
<!-- Copied from: https://jsfiddle.net/solodev/yw7y4wez -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Pagination Example</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.solodev.com/assets/pagination/jquery.twbsPagination.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        
        .page {
            display: none;
        }
        
        .page-active {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {

            $('#pagination-demo').twbsPagination({
                totalPages: 5,
                // the current page that show on start
                startPage: 1,

                // maximum visible pages
                visiblePages: 5,

                initiateStartPageClick: true,

                // template for pagination links
                href: false,

                // variable name in href template for page number
                hrefVariable: '{{number}}',

                // Text labels
                first: 'First',
                prev: 'Previous',
                next: 'Next',
                last: 'Last',

                // carousel-style pagination
                loop: false,

                // callback function
                onPageClick: function(event, page) {
                    $('.page-active').removeClass('page-active');
                    $('#page' + page).addClass('page-active');
                },

                // pagination Classes
                paginationClass: 'pagination',
                nextClass: 'next',
                prevClass: 'prev',
                lastClass: 'last',
                firstClass: 'first',
                pageClass: 'page',
                activeClass: 'active',
                disabledClass: 'disabled'

            });

        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron page" id="page1">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="display-3">Adding Pagination to your Website</h1>
                <p class="lead">In this article we teach you how to add pagination, an excellent way to navigate large amounts of content, to your website using a jQuery Bootstrap Plugin.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="https://www.solodev.com/blog/web-design/adding-pagination-to-your-website.stml" role="button">Learn More</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron page" id="page2">
            <h1 class="display-3">Not Another Jumbotron</h1>
            <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron page" id="page3">
            <h1 class="display-3">Data. Data. Data.</h1>
            <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default responsive navbar works. It's placed within a <code>.container</code> to limit its width and will scroll with the rest of the page's content.
            </p>
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/navbar" role="button">View navbar docs »</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron page" id="page4">
            <h1 style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">Buy Now!</h1>
            <p class="lead" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet.</p>
            <p style="-webkit-user-select: auto;"><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button" style="-webkit-user-select: auto;">Get
                    started today</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron page" id="page5">
            <h1 class="cover-heading">Cover your page.</h1>
            <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
            <p class="lead">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Learn more</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <ul id="pagination-demo" class="pagination-lg pull-right"></ul>
    </div>

    <script>
        // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
        if (window.parent && window.parent.parent) {
            window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
                height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
                slug: "yw7y4wez"
            }], "*")
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a sample working version of code,

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function runScraper() {
  let browser = {};
  let page = {};
  const url = 'http://localhost:8080';

  // open the page and wait
  async function navigate() {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
  }

  async function scrapeData() {
    const headerSel = 'h1';
    // wait for element
    await page.waitFor(headerSel);
    return page.evaluate((selector) => {
      const target = document.querySelector(selector);

      // get the data
      const text = target.innerText;

      // remove element so the waiting function works
      target.remove();
      return text;
    }, headerSel);
  }

  // this is a sample concept of pagination
  // it will vary from page to page because not all site have same type of pagination

  async function paginate() {
    // manually check if the next button is available or not
    const nextBtnDisabled = !!(await page.$('.next.disabled'));
    if (!nextBtnDisabled) {
      // since it's not disable, click it
      await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('.next').click());

      // just some random waiting function
      await page.waitFor(100);
      return true;
    }
    console.log({ nextBtnDisabled });
  }

  /**
   * Scraping Logic
   */
  await navigate();

  // Scrape 5 pages
  for (const pageNum of [...Array(5).keys()]) {
    const title = await scrapeData();
    console.log(pageNum + 1, title);
    await paginate();
  }
}

runScraper();
```

Result:

```
Server running at 8080
1 'Adding Pagination to your Website'
2 'Not Another Jumbotron'
3 'Data. Data. Data.'
4 'Buy Now!'
5 'Cover your page.'
{ nextBtnDisabled: true }
```

I did not share the server code, it's basically the html snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

use attribute **footerTemplate** with **displayHeaderFooter** for show pages originally using puppeteer API

```
await page.pdf({
  path: 'hacks.pdf',
  format: 'A4',
  displayHeaderFooter: true,
  footerTemplate: '<div><div class='pageNumber'></div> <div>/</div><div class='totalPages'></div></div>'
});
```

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions

> **footerTemplate**  HTML template for the print footer.

// Should be valid HTML markup with following **CSS classes** used to inject printing values into them:

//  - **date** formatted print date

//  - **title** document title

//  - **url** document location

//  - **pageNumber** current page number

//  - **totalPages** total pages in the document